# How do I select a specific set of data within a data in laravel with the use of dynamo db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, amazon-dynamodb

I am fairly new to laravel so I would like to know how do you grab a the data from 'data' with laravel query

the dynamo database is like this

```
{
 "subdomain": "subdomain",
 "uuid": "uuid_1234",
 "data": {
  "credit_limit": 1200,
  "id": 1234,
  "name": "Allan",
  "number": 651234568
 }
}
```

and i want to only get from the database

```
"credit_limit": 1200,
  "id": 1234,
  "name": "Allan",
  "number": 651234568
```

the code I used is

```
$dynamo = DB::connection('dynamo')
                ->table('module_details')
                ->whereIndex('subdomain-index')
                ->where('uuid', '=', strtolower($this->Class).'_'.array_get($result['data'], 'id'))
                ->wherePartitionKey('subdomain', '=', Config::get('node.subdomain'))
                ->select('data')
                ->get();
```

but this code gave me the result of

```
"data": {
  "credit_limit": 1200,
  "id": 1234,
  "name": "Allan",
  "number": 651234568
 }
```

Comment: Can you include your whole controller? how do you output the data from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$dynamo = DB::connection('dynamo')
                ->table('module_details')
                ->whereIndex('subdomain-index')
                ->where('uuid', '=', strtolower($this->Class).'_'.array_get($result['data'], 'id'))
                ->wherePartitionKey('subdomain', '=', Config::get('node.subdomain'))
                ->select('data.credit_limit','data.id','data.name','data.number')
                ->get();
```

it will give you specific data that you want